# Need help determining output of a short C program containing ASM

Tags: gcc, assembly, output, x86-64, inline-assembly

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int var1 = 12;
    int var2 = 5;

    asm volatile("mov %3, %0 \n"
                 "add %2, %1" : "=r"(var1), "=r"(var2) : "r"(var1), "r"(var2));

    /*
    asm volatile("mov %1, %0 \n"
                 "add %0, %1" : "+r"(var1), "+r"(var2));*/
    /*
    asm volatile("mov %1, %0" : "=r"(var1) : "r"(var2));
    asm volatile("add %1, %0" : "=r"(var2) : "r"(var1));*/


    printf("var1 = %d, var2 = %d\n", var1, var2);

    return 0;
}
```

The first and second pieces of commented `asm` both result in

```
var1 = 5, var2 = 10
```

which is as I expect -- `var1` assigned using `var2`, then both added together to obtain new `var2`.

I use

```
gcc test.c
```

within centos7 on x86_64 machine to compile, so I think I'm using GAS (which means both `add` and `mov` have their src/dst reg as 1st/2nd operand).

So, My problem here is, why would the first `asm` generate the following result:

```
var1 = 5, var2 = 24
```

I must admit the first `asm` looks quite nasty (at least to me, which is why I tried the other two versions to verify my thought), but is it "wrong" ? Or, does it totally make no sense to write so?

If, for example, it's actually acceptable to write such `asm` code, then I could not figure out why its output looks like that. Is it machine/abi dependent or what? Why doesn't it also give `var1 = 5, var2 = 10` ?

I'm really a newbie for x86 assembly, so plz forgive me for this question if it looks dumb, and THANK YOU in advance for taking time to read my question.

Comment: The code is unsafe: `"=r"(var1)` is missing an early clobber but you write it before reading both inputs.  So either output was possible, depending on the compiler's choices.  This isn't an assembly problem, it's a GNU C *inline* asm problem in describing your asm snippet to the compiler.  Don't use inline asm until you already understand asm, and how GCC thinks about constraints and optimization.

Comment: examine the disassembly of this function to see what you have created and why it isnt working.  start with real assembly language first then figure out there is almost no reason to use inline.  But if you do the only way to be successful is to constantly disassemble and examine the output.